# suitable data type to save string larger than 8000 charachter

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, large-text

what is the suitable data type to save string more than 8000 character in SQL database?

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Is `CREATE TABLE` failing? Or are you trying to `declare @theString varchar(max)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SQL Server 2005+ `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)` depending on whether you need to save as unicode or not.

If you don't have this requirement (or anticipate ever needing it) the `varchar` option is more space efficient.

You don't give a specific version of SQL Server in your question. Pre 2005 it would have been the `text` datatype.

NB: In answer to your comment use 'varchar(max)' exactly as written. Don't substitute a number in for "max"!

Comment: I tried varchar(max) and nvarchar(max) but failed because max = 4000 for nvar and 8000 for var

Comment: Can you post the full piece of code that fails? Or explain in what context you are using it and getting a problem?

Comment: @salamonti: varchar(max) can **definitely** handle a lot more than 8000 characters! THere must be something else that's wrong with your SQL code or process - please post more info!

Comment: @salamonti You seem to have completely disregarded the request for further details but one more guess might be that if you are using it in ADO.NET in a place that requires a number you need to use -1.

Comment: sorry but it is worked good sorry for late the problem not in the data type I solved the problem and now working perfect thanks for help